# AFL fuzzer program flags

Tags: linux, fuzzing, american-fuzzy-lop

I am trying to fuzz on a program using afl-fuzzer.
However, I need the fuzzer to feed the input files to the program with a specific flag (eg. --flag input-file.xxx).
Is there a way to do this ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use syntax

```
afl-fuzz -i in-dir -o out-dir -other -afl -parameters -- ./your-program --flag @@
```

AFL will substitute `@@` with input file name.

Or you can specify the `-f filename` AFL option and specify that file name in your program's arguments, config file, environment variables -- anywhere. By default, AFL passes input to the `stdin` of the program under test.

Comment: Yup that was I needed.. In fact that's what I was doing without realizing it worked ! Thank you !!